# Is there a way to convert string to list and update a value of list and convert it back to string in one line

Tags: python

What I want to achieve

```
value = 'a.b.c.d.e'
new_value = value.split('.')
new_value[-1] = F
''.join(new_value)
```

Now I would like to achieve this in one line. something like below

```
''.join(value[-1] = F in value.split('.'))
```

my above expression throws error because it is kind of wrong so is there a possible way to achieve this

Comment: `'.'.join(value.split('.')[:-1] + ['10'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value should be "1.2.3.4.5" and join doesn't work for int. You should use new_value[-1]='10' instead.

```
''.join(value.split('.')[:-1]+['10'])
```

Comment: i have updated value as string to avoid int confusion

Comment: @user3812837 You're welcome! You forgot to modify your solution.